# Facebook get AdImage url from image_hash

Tags: python, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

My code (python-business-sdk):

```py
account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
img = account.get_ad_images(params={'hashes': ['6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79'})[0]
print(img['url'])  # doesnt work
primt(img[AdImage.Field.url])  # doesnt work
```

I do the request but get only id and hash in my `img` var (AdImage obj):

```py
'{..., _json': {'hash': '6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79', 'id': '36246837:6b709f0275d0bdf18fb78ef08492ee79'}}}
```

But i need the url of image, here's documentation with the fields (`url` is there) but i don't receive those or don't know how to get..
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image#examples_read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Just add fields argument to get_ad_images**